# Insert * before underlined text in Word

Tags: regex, ms-word, replace

I have a page full of text like this (**NOTE:** the `c.` is underlined, but you can't underline text in markdown.)

> 1. This is sample question text. Isn't it beautiful how the authors crafted this question? God it makes me want to sing just reading it. And the answers! Just wait until you get to the answers choices; that is where they really shine.
>
> a. This is the first answer
>
> b. BAM! Second answer
>
> c. Here is the correct answer
>
> d. You missed it! That last one was the correct one

And I want to insert a `*` before the underlined `c.` so it looks like

> 1. This is sample question text. Isn't it beautiful how the authors crafted this question? God it makes me want to sing just reading it. And the answers! Just wait until you get to the answers choices; that is where they really shine.
>
> a. This is the first answer
>
> b. BAM! Second answer
>
> *c. Here is the correct answer
>
> d. You missed it! That last one was the correct one

I know there is a way to do this with the Find/Replace dialog in Word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the [more>>], [format] and [special] buttons in Find and replace dialog

```
Find what:     ^$
Format:        Underline

Replace with:  *^&
```

Comment: This one is really close but it put a `*` before _and_ after the `c.` **Edit:** Looks like the update from `^?` to `^$` fixed it!

Answer (score 1):

[This tutorial](http://www.wambooli.com/help/word/find_formatting/) is what you are looking for. You can search for the format and replace with placeholders as described [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/help/add-power-to-word-searches-with-regular-expressions-HA001087305.aspx)